# Copy the content one IEnumerable to another after checking the index of each record

Tags: c#, wpf, ienumerable

I want to copy the record from one IEnumerable to another after checking the index of the record. pvm consists of set of records with n number of columns and m number of rows. In view_filter method i am checking index. If the condition holds good I want to copy record to _invMstrSrchResults. Index gets checked one by one.

```cs
        public PagingViewModel(IEnumerable<InventoryMasterItem> pvm)
        {            
            ViewList = new CollectionViewSource();
            ViewList.Source = pvm;
            ViewList.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(view_Filter);

            CurrentPageIndex = 0;
            itemcount = 100;
            CalculateTotalPages();            
        }

        private IEnumerable<InventoryMasterItem> _invMstrSrchResults;

        void view_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = ((InventoryMasterItem)e.Item).indexNo - 1;
            if (index >= itemPerPage * CurrentPageIndex && index < itemPerPage * (CurrentPageIndex + 1))
            {
                 // I want to copy record from pvm to _invMstrSrchResults here
                 e.Accepted = true;               
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilterEventArgs` should be holding an `InventoryMasterItem` object which you can retrieve in `view_Filter`. Additionally, you may need to a create a different collection temporarily, `List<InventoryMasterItem>` and then cast it to an `IEnumerable<InventoryMasterItem>`:

```
InventoryMasterItem item = e.Item as InventoryMasterItem;
var list = new List<InventoryMasterItem>();
list.Add(item);
_invMstrSrchResults = list.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: only one record is getting stored. There are 15 records. I think each time it enters the condition block, record is getting replaced.

Comment: private IEnumerable<InventoryMasterItem> _invMstrSrchResults;
        void view_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            InventoryMasterItem item = e.Item as InventoryMasterItem;
            int index = ((InventoryMasterItem)e.Item).indexNo - 1;
            if (index >= itemPerPage * CurrentPageIndex && index < itemPerPage * (CurrentPageIndex + 1))
            {
                var list = new List<InventoryMasterItem>();
                list.Add(item);
                _invMstrSrchResults = list.AsEnumerable();
            }
        }